# Using equationsToMatrix with functions (dependent variables)

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, state-space

I'm trying to find state space model of inverted (one piece) pendulum using the `equationsToMatrix` function. I'm using the following code:

```
%Declaration of Variables
syms x(t) t M m ddx(t) l th(t) ddth(t) dth(t) b1 b2 dx(t) F(t) I

%Nonlinear Equations
eqn1=eq((I+m*l^2)*ddth+m*l*cos(th)*ddx-m*g*l*sin(th)+b2*dth,0)
eqn2=eq((M+m)*ddx+m*l*cos(th)*ddth-m*l*sin(th)*(dth)^2+b1*dx,F)

%Linear Equations
eqn1L=subs (eqn1,[cos(th),sin(th(t)),dth(t)^2],[1,th(t),0])
eqn2L=subs (eqn2,[cos(th),sin(th(t)),dth(t)^2],[1,th(t),0])

%Finding State Space Model
[A,B]=equationsToMatrix([eqn2L,eqn1L],[x(t),dx(t),th(t),dth(t)])
C=[1 0 0 0;0 1 0 0;0 0 1 0;0 0 0 1];
D=[0;0;0;0];

sys = ss(A,B,C,D)
```

MATLAB throws the following error:

> Error using `sym.getEqnsVars`>`checkVariables` (line 92)
> The second argument must be a vector of symbolic variables.
>
> Error in `sym.getEqnsVars` (line 54)
> `checkVariables(vars);`
>
> Error in `sym/equationsToMatrix` (line 55)
> `[eqns,vars] = sym.getEqnsVars(argv{:});`
>
> Error in `Linearization_Test` (line 10)
> `[A,B]=equationsToMatrix([eqn2L,eqn1L],[x(t),dx(t),th(t),dth(t)])`

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should substitute the variables with ones that has no time dependency:

```
syms x_ dx_ th_ dth_
X = [x(t),dx(t),th(t),dth(t)];
X_ = [x_,dx_,th_,dth_];
[A,B]=equationsToMatrix(subs([eqn2L,eqn1L], X, X_),X_)
```

Comment: The answer was direct and right, but to give attention for people who may read this question and answer, state space model (which is out of the question's field) needs additional corrections.

Comment: @IsamAsaad consider mentioning those corrections (as a comment may be), just in case a random googler happens to visit this post.

Comment: @Sardar Usama of course, but I just wanted to say that A and B Matrices are not usable yet to construct the desired state space model.